# How to line break in css

Tags: html, css

I have such class in my css

```
.this br {
    display: none;
}
    
\@media (max-width : 600px) {
    .this br {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
```

and html

```
<div class="this"><br><br><br><br></div>
```

How can i put line break in css
so that i can just use class `<div class="this"></div>`

Comment: margin or padding can create a space alike a few linebreaks `.this{padding-top:3.6em}` is an average height of 3 lines

Comment: Can you provide an example with some content and who you would like it to be displayed?

Comment: ".this" does already break your line since "div" is a block-level element. If you want more space, you could use margin/padding like G-Cyrillus said.

Comment: thanks guys padding-top:3.6em has worked for me